# How to Get Lists for Uri Templates based on other Ids

Tags: rest

Lets say I have a couple URI template endpoint for a REST API as such:

`"/events"` - gives me all events

```
"/events/{eventId}"
```

`"/events/2234"` - gives me the event specified by the eventId

What if I wanted all events by a specific broker.  I was thinking maybe this:

```
"/events/{brokerId}"
```

e.g.
`"events/2345"` - gives me all the events for the specific BrokerId

problem is how would the service know if the incoming url is sending in a broker vs. eventId?  the /2234 and /2345 are indistinguishable.

I'm wondering how this is handled in REST.  Do most people typically do something like:

```
"events/broker/{brokerId}"
```

or do they somehow specify what type of Id it is some other way?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about others, but I would probably do something like:

```
/brokers/{brokerId}/events
```

For example:

```
/brokers/2345/events
```

Of course, you could always do something less rest-ful, such as:

```
/events?brokerId=2345
```

Comment: yea I was thinking about something like this too, you would go through the broker to get his events

Comment: Much of this decision depends heavily on how your particular application operates.

Comment: right, but was just thinking 2nd level resources period...so really any api, sure it depends on relationships but that's not what I was asking.  I'm more trying to figure out how combinations are presented...when you start going beyond just the first level of resources meaning just {resource}/{resourceId}